# append existing element to div as a first/last child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please ignore this question from now. I made a huge mistake. :-)

I have this problem with appending a div (a user div with html in it)from one div to another div. I want to be able to move the "`user_u_1`"-divs between the containing "`regionheader`"-divs. Their classes should change also. I have a [Fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfm0awov/9/) prepared.
Right now if a want to append a div from the above div to the second div it appends it to the last one.

the structure is as follows:

```
<div id="onlineList">

    <div class="regionheader" id="one">
        <span class="regionspan"><h3>One</h3></span>
        <div id="user_u_1" class="One" name="Joe">1</div>
        <div id="user_u_2" class="One" name="Joe">2</div>
        <div id="user_u_3" class="One" name="Joe">3</div>
    </div>

    <div class="regionheader" id="two">
        <span class="regionspan"><h3>Two</h3></span>
        <div id="user_u_4" class="Two" name="Joe">4</div>
        <div id="user_u_5" class="Two" name="Joe">5</div>
        <div id="user_u_6" class="Two" name="Joe">6</div>
    </div>

    <div class="regionheader" id="three">
        <span class="regionspan"><h3>three</h3></span>
        <div id="user_u_7" class="three" name="Joe">7</div>
        <div id="user_u_8" class="three" name="Joe">8</div>
        <div id="user_u_8" class="three" name="Joe">9</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your HTML.

The offending line:

```
<div id="user_u_4" class="Two" name="Joe" >4<html/div>
```

Should be:

```
<div id="user_u_4" class="Two" name="Joe" >4</div>
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfm0awov/10/) that works.

Comment: I.ve corrected it. Indeed the fdle works now but what if i don't know in what div it is and you must use its class to determine that it should move to the first/last position in its parent?

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard from where you are now. One method would be to set an event listener on the entire group and then check `event.target` to get the element that was clicked. From there you can access its classes and parents.

Comment: Made a quick update to the fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/sfm0awov/13/